# Tips on avoiding limits imposed by double precision

Tags: matlab, double, iteration, precision

I am using Matlab to solve a differential equation which has a free parameter. The details of the equation are not relevant to my question. This parameter has to be iterated upon to obtain a good output. As the parameter is iterated, the output improves, but eventually this improvement stops due to the precision accuracy set by Matlab. That is, eventually I end up with lower and upper bound estimates for my parameter where the separation between these bounds is so small that there is no number that exists between them (by number I mean a number that the computer can use). At this point, since there is no better estimate for my parameter, I can't improve on it.

The obvious solution would be using higher than double precision, but as far as I know this is not possible in Matlab. Does anybody have any general tips on how to circumvent this limitation? I'm open to all suggestions.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you need precision of 0.00000000000000000000001 ? There is practically no way of getting better. Maybe with some personalized architecture computers? However note: we have sent people to the moon, build particle accelerators and do macroeconomics with this precision, are you **sure** you need more?

Comment: Actually, you can get a higher precision - see [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html).

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, you can get higher precision as Dev-il suggests. But, please consider again of you really really need it

Comment: In most of the cases I am studying I don't need higher precision, but there are a few instances where I want to go beyond this level of accuracy.

As for vpa, isn't this limited too by double precision?

Comment: @Dev-iL `vpa` only provides more precision when working with symbolic inputs. Passing numeric expressions to `vpa` just give you more digits of double precision round-off error.

Comment: Well, nobody said it was a drop-in replacement.. But that's what you can do, unless you want to go to ["infinite precision" Mathematica](https://youtu.be/_sWY0FATWXw?t=650)....

Comment: You need to provide a concrete example of what you're trying to do and why you need this to get any more specific help. Depending on the problem, one can often apply various numerical trick to improve accuracy/precision (see [this for example](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2015/03/02/triple-precision-accumlated-inner-product/)).

Comment: @excaza, et al.: one definitely needs to be careful using `vpa` but it can be used for truly arbitrary precision just like Mathematica. For example, I've used it calculate a million digits of `pi`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, one can use symbolic types to work with truly arbitrary precision? I looked up this in the documentation and played around and the only draw-back I could find is the computation time. Other than this, is symbolic computation with numeric data truly perfect in terms of accuracy? Seems almost too good to be true.